# Delivery plans Target date

Tags: date, azure-devops

I used to be able to edit the target date just by moving the edge of the card on delivery plans. But Today, every story I create has the target date associated to the iteration and not the day it should finish.

Is this any type of configuration I'm missing os is it a bug from devops?

Best,
Ricardo

I tried to find a configuration that addresses this issue but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Check this practics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops#best-practices-for-using-a-delivery-plan

> Use Start Date and Iteration to specify the time frame for a work
> item. Or, use Start Date and Target Date. However, don't specify both
> Iteration and Target Date for a work item. Target Date will always
> override the Iteration end date on the plan.

So.. you may set `Target Date` in your plan manually then the delivery plan will use `Target Date` as a planning point.

On the screenshot, the first work item uses start and target dates, and the second one start date and iteration:

[image]